# How to use machine learning to classify text using available keywords?

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification, lda, topic-modeling

I have around 200 keywords for 15 different categories, I want to apply machine learning to classify/detect the text for different category.

I have used LDA topic modelling, but that is not helpful as it is giving topic explicitly. What can else to used for this?

Comment: Latent Semantic Indexing (LSI) or Relational Topic Models (RTM). I have not personally used these models but I have found these models from the literature (scholarly articles)

Comment: @YatShan, I have applied both LSI and LND but, result is not as desired.